# Testing Android In-App-Purchase: Purchased subscription canccelled automatically instead of auto renew?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I'm implementing an in-app purchase in android. During Testing I purchased a subscription package of 3 months, which would be [auto renewed after 10 minutes](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/01/faster-renewals-for-test-subscriptions.html), but after 5 minutes I'm getting email that that purchased has been cancelled, So not getting renewal after 10 minutes, I checked this for 2 to 3 times.

Does it require any particular settings to get auto renew in Testing flow?
Or How to test purchase>renew>cancel flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `billingClient.acknowledgePurchase()`after you get `purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED` and after you verify the signature

if not the purchase for both in-app products and subscriptions is refunded/cancelled